lang="ur" changes how safari displays text
I'm facing an issue where setting lang="ur" on the html element changes the way Safari displays text:


const base = `
<html lang="ar">
<head>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  ٹیسٹ
</body>
</html>
`

const a = document.createElement('iframe')
a.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + base;

const b = document.createElement('iframe')
b.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + base.replace('ar','ur');

document.body.appendChild(a);
document.body.appendChild(b);



Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?


Perhaps this one explains it? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304520/why-is-the-arabic-font-on-my-iphone-different-from-what-it-is-supposed-to-be

Have you checked if Helvetica Neue optimized for Arabic or Urdu scripts?

@NijatMursali based on https://urdufonts.com/fonts/helvetica-neue-lt-w20/ I assumed as much.

I see, never worked worked with it, but you might check the link @mplungjan shared that actually explains it..

@mplungjan assuming that is the reason, how could I fix this? I can't tell my app users to change their language settings. And we set lang='[code]' for all languages we support - adding an exception for Urdu should be considered as a last resort - I would prefer a clean solution.

Seems you are SOL - try https://www.apple.com/feedback/

According to Font Book on MacOS, the bundled version of Helvetica Neue doesn't actually include any Arabic characters. Arial does though.


const base = `
<html lang="ar">
<head>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  ٹیسٹ
</body>
</html>
`

const a = document.createElement('iframe')
a.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + base;

const b = document.createElement('iframe')
b.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + base.replace('ar','ur');

document.body.appendChild(a);
document.body.appendChild(b);




I tried all fonts in the Font Book that support Urdu and found out that 'Geeza Pro' is used unless lang='ur'
